# Video player doesn't stop loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I'm developing an app where I want to play an mp4 video from a remote HTTP URL. Here is the code I have:

```
// Prepare URL
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://static.winterlightfilms.com/%@/film.mp4", responseObject];
NSLog(urlString);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
```

I can verify from the NSLog line that the video exists and it is playable on a web browser. However, the player shows the "loading" wheel forever. How can I get the video to play?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
// Prepare URL
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://static.winterlightfilms.com/%@/film.mp4", responseObject];
NSLog(urlString);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[mpvc.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```